# pages created in Site pages library does not show page name in "Titletext" place holder

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, master-page, libraries

I created a publishing site in sharepoint and created one page using browser, and one page using `sharepoint designer`. The home page and page created using browser are in `"pages" library` and page created using designer is in `"Site Pages" library`. I customized my pages by attaching a new master page just excluding `toplink bar` and `navigation bar`. now the pages in `"pages"` library shows site name and page name in `"TitleText" place holder`. But the pages in `"Site Pages"` library only show site name in `"TitleText"`. What is wrong?
Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The "Pages" library is a publishing page library and will use page layouts.

The "Site Pages" library can have completely different content types, most likely wiki pages or web part pages.

Don't confuse the two types of libraries. They use completely different architectures.

A good summary of the different kinds of libraries can be had here: http://nikpatel.net/2012/06/08/wiki-pages-vs-web-part-pages-for-sharepoint-intranet-content-pages/